# How to redirect old URL to the new one in the same domain

Tags: redirect

I got some problem. I need to redirect my old links (from other cms installation) to new one.
Actually i got url:

http://domain.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=517

and i need to redirect it to:

http://domain.com/category-1

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score -1):

I'm in need of doing this too but with muliple URLs to one page. I know this'll work for one URL in the htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/nomination-italy_c123.aspx/.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/nomination
```

but what about several?

www.mywebsite.com/nomination-italy_c123.aspx

www.mywebsite.com/nomination-bracelets_c192.aspx

www.mywebsite.com/nomination-rings_c278.aspx

www.mywebsite.com/nomination-big-charms_c356.aspx

www.mywebsite.com/nomination-necklaces_c194.aspx

to

http://www.mywebsite.com/nomination